# How to extract String from a Unicoded JSONObject in Python?

Tags: python, json

I'm getting the below error when I try to parse a String with Unicodes like ' symbol and Emojis, etc  :

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\U0001f33b' in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Sample Object:

```
{"user":{"name":"\u0e2a\u0e31\u0e48\u0e07\u0e14\u0e48\u0e27\u0e19 \u0e2b\u0e21\u0e14\u0e44\u0e27 \u0e40\u0e14\u0e23\u0e2a\u0e41\u0e1f\u0e0a\u0e31\u0e48\u0e19\u0e21\u0e32\u0e43\u0e2b\u0e21\u0e48 \u0e23\u0e32\u0e04\u0e32\u0e40\u0e1a\u0e32\u0e46 \u0e2a\u0e48\u0e07\u0e17\u0e31\u0e48\u0e27\u0e44\u0e17\u0e22 \u0e44\u0e14\u0e49\u0e02\u0e2d\u0e07\u0e0a\u0e31\u0e27\u0e23\u0e4c\u0e08\u0e49\u0e32 \u0e2a\u0e19\u0e43\u0e08\u0e15\u0e34\u0e14\u0e15\u0e48\u0e2d\u0e2a\u0e2d\u0e1a\u0e16\u0e32\u0e21 Is it","tag":"XYZ"}}
```

I'm able to extract tag value, but I'm unable to extract name value.

Here is my code:

```
dict = json.loads(json_data)
print('Tag - 'dict['user']['tag'])
print('Name - 'dict['user']['name'])
```

Comment: There's no "Unicoded" string there. It's actually an ASCIIed string, if anything. It's a string with some escape sequences. You don't need them in JSON or HTML. **THIS PAGE IS UNICODE**. Just check the encoding using Developer tools - it's UTF8. Then check the source - no escape sequences are used. Plain text

Comment: The problem is that whoever created that string tried to convert it to *ASCII* using escape sequences. They should fix their bug and emit proper JSON strings using a UTF8 *encoding*. Otherwise you'll have to guess which language was used to ASCIIfy the string and use the appropriate functions to convert it back to normal text.

Comment: Or perhaps someone copied a *source code literal string* into the output? In C# these escape sequences produce the same result as this string `"สั่งด่วน หมดไว เดรสแฟชั่นมาใหม่ ราคาเบาๆ ส่งทั่วไทย ได้ของชัวร์จ้า สนใจติดต่อสอบถาม Is it"`. No symbols or emojis here, and as you can see

Comment: Are those objects stored in a file?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Looks like I haven't phrased my question properly. I'm actually trying to scrape html data. What should be my approach?

Comment: @Anirudh don't. You don't need to. StackOverflow uses ASP.NET which sends HTML using UTF8. That's why I told you to check the encoding and source code for this page. You *DON'T* need to encode anything. HTML works just fine. So does JSON.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I need to scrape data from a webpage.

Comment: @Anirudh Do you want display username in **console**??

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes I need to print name and save it in an excel file.

Comment: That is probably not your code, as 'Tag - 'dict... is not valid python. Please state what you're actually using :-)

Comment: It's **Melvin**... Don't expect the console to display complex non-ASCII characters. The data can be saved in Excel though.

Comment: @MelvinAbraham How do I Save name? What should be my approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the data in `CSV` file format which could also be opened using Excel. When you open a file in this way: `open(filename, "w")` then you can only store ASCII characters, but if you try to store Unicode data this way, you would get `UnicodeEncodeError`. In order for you to store Unicode data, you need to open the file with `UTF-8` encoding.

```
mydict = json.loads(json_data)  # or whatever dictionary it is...

# Open the file with UTF-8 encoding, most important step
f = open("userdata.csv", "w", encoding='utf-8')

f.write(mydict['user']['name'] + ", " + mydict['user']['tag'] + "\n")
f.close()
```

Feel free to change the code based on the data you have.
That's it...